# Usage of result from one column in computation in different column in MSSQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to use the result from one column in computation in later columns in MS SQL Server.

Below is my SQL code:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT 'EURUSD' AS a) AS symbol_name,
(SELECT TOP 1  ROUND(p.BidLast,5) FROM mt5_prices p WHERE p.Symbol LIKE 'EURUSD%') AS Bid,

(SELECT SUM(m.Volume) 
FROM mt5_positions m
WHERE m.Symbol LIKE 'EURUSD%' AND m.Login IN (SELECT u.Login FROM mt5_users u WHERE u."Group" LIKE 'real%') AND m."Action" = 0) AS TotalBuy,

(SELECT CASE 
WHEN 'EURUSD' LIKE 'USOIL%' OR 'EURUSD' LIKE 'UKOIL%' OR 'EURUSD' LIKE 'Bund%' THEN ROUND(TotalBuy/10*Bid,2) 
WHEN 'EURUSD' LIKE 'NGAS%' OR 'EURUSD' LIKE 'Copper%' THEN ROUND(TotalBuy/1*Bid,2)
ELSE ROUND(TotalBuy/100*Bid,2) END) AS ExpositionBuyLots
```

Of course, the error returned is:

> SQL Error (207): Invalid column name 'TotalBuy'
>   Invalid column name 'Bid'.

**My question is:** How can I use the **already** (or, so to speak "on-the-fly") computed result from columns `TotalBuy` and `Bid`? I read about computed columns, but unfortunately, modification of database is not possible.

MS SQL Server 2012 version.

EDIT: The above functionality is available in MySQL, I hope in MS SQL this can be achieved too.
If someone is interested about the solution (I chose @Damien because it is closest one to the original MySQL query (yes, it is query, rewritten from MySQL to MSSQL), i.e. require only small SQL modification):

```
SELECT * FROM    
(SELECT 'EURUSD' AS symbol_name) symbol_name

CROSS apply

(SELECT TOP 1  ROUND(p.AskLast,5) AS Ask FROM mt5_prices p WHERE p.Symbol LIKE 'EURUSD%') Ask

CROSS apply

(SELECT TOP 1  ROUND(p.BidLast,5) AS Bid FROM mt5_prices p WHERE p.Symbol LIKE 'EURUSD%') Bid

CROSS apply

(SELECT SUM(m.Volume) AS TotalBuy
FROM mt5_positions m
WHERE m.Symbol LIKE 'EURUSD%' AND m.Login IN (SELECT u.Login FROM mt5_users u WHERE u."Group" LIKE 'real%') AND m."Action" = 0) TotalBuy

CROSS apply

(SELECT SUM(m.Volume) AS TotalSell
FROM mt5_positions m
WHERE m.Symbol LIKE 'EURUSD%' AND m.Login IN (SELECT u.Login FROM mt5_users u WHERE u."Group" LIKE 'real%') AND m."Action" = 1) TotalSell

CROSS apply

(SELECT (CASE 
WHEN 'EURUSD' LIKE 'USOIL%' OR 'EURUSD' LIKE 'UKOIL%' OR 'EURUSD' LIKE 'Bund%' THEN ROUND(TotalBuy/10*Bid,2) 
WHEN 'EURUSD' LIKE 'NGAS%' OR 'EURUSD' LIKE 'Copper%' THEN ROUND(TotalBuy/1*Bid,2)
ELSE ROUND(TotalBuy/100*Bid,2) END) AS ExpositionBuyLots) ExpositionBuyLots
```

Comment: Can you use a temp table to store all your calculations in?

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot get the results from a SQL query like yours, unless your columns are part of the schema (like a computed column). The  solution I have in mind at the moment is to use a temporary table (that you would delete later), to store the results. I think a better way could of doing this is also possible.

Comment: @AlbertoSolano - introducing a temp table is a poor approach, since it means that you're breaking the query into multiple independent queries - offering the server fewer opportunities to optimize the logical query "as a whole". Subqueries keep everything contained in a single query.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Of course, temporary tables are not the solution to all the problems. Now that I think deeper about the problem, I agree with you. Subqueries should solve the problem in the best possible way. :-)

Comment: There's a lot wrong with your query. Your CASE statement will always hit the ELSE branch because you're comparing a literal to values that won't match in each of the WHEN conditions. Your SELECT statement is a bunch of sub-queries to return single values. I'm fairly certain you're way off the mark of whatever you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @AlbertoSolano Each sub-query returns a single value. Forget temporary tables - local variables would suffice!

Comment: @Craig Young - You would be right about the `CASE` statement in this case, I didn't mention that it will be dynamic parameter, real query is a bit longer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cross apply` (or subqueries) to introduce additional `select` clauses. Each `select` clause is computed "as if" all expressions are computed in parallel - that's why there cannot be dependencies between the expressions within a single `select` clause.

E.g.:

```
select
    *
from
    sys.objects
        cross apply
    (select object_id + 10 as mega_object_id) u
        cross apply
    (select mega_object_id / 30 as little_object_id) w
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use another sub query block to achieve this:

```
SELECT (
        CASE 
            WHEN 'EURUSD' LIKE 'USOIL%'
                OR 'EURUSD' LIKE 'UKOIL%'
                OR 'EURUSD' LIKE 'Bund%'
                THEN ROUND(TotalBuy / 10 * Bid, 2)
            WHEN 'EURUSD' LIKE 'NGAS%'
                OR 'EURUSD' LIKE 'Copper%'
                THEN ROUND(TotalBuy / 1 * Bid, 2)
            ELSE ROUND(TotalBuy / 100 * Bid, 2)
            END
        ) AS ExpositionBuyLots, *
FROM (
    SELECT ( SELECT 'EURUSD' AS a ) AS symbol_name
          ,( SELECT TOP 1 ROUND(p.BidLast, 5)
            FROM mt5_prices p
            WHERE p.Symbol LIKE 'EURUSD%'
            ) AS Bid
          ,( SELECT SUM(m.Volume)
            FROM mt5_positions m
            WHERE m.Symbol LIKE 'EURUSD%'
                AND m.LOGIN IN (
                    SELECT u.LOGIN
                    FROM mt5_users u
                    WHERE u."Group" LIKE 'real%'
                    )
                AND m."Action" = 0
            ) AS TotalBuy
    ) AS R
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, it works, however I believe there should be less complex way to achieve it - the sub-query is something I try to avoid.

Comment: @bodi0 Your original query is _all_ sub-queries!

Comment: @Craig Young - You are right, that's why I prefer to minimize them (unless there is no performance impact **and** code uglifying).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `APPLY` operator. You can use values from `YourTable` in `APPLY`

```
SELECT 
    ExpositionBuyLots = CASE 
        WHEN 'EURUSD' LIKE 'USOIL%' OR 'EURUSD' LIKE 'UKOIL%' OR 'EURUSD' LIKE 'Bund%' THEN ROUND(ComputedValues.TotalBuy/10*ComputedValues.Bid,2) 
        WHEN 'EURUSD' LIKE 'NGAS%' OR 'EURUSD' LIKE 'Copper%' THEN ROUND(ComputedValues.TotalBuy/1*ComputedValues.Bid,2)
        ELSE ROUND(ComputedValues.TotalBuy/100 * ComputedValues.Bid,2) END
FROM YourTable
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT
        symbol_name = 'EURUSD',
        Bid         = (SELECT TOP 1  ROUND(p.BidLast,5) FROM mt5_prices p WHERE p.Symbol LIKE 'EURUSD%') ,
        TotalBuy    = (SELECT SUM(m.Volume) 
                          FROM mt5_positions m
                          WHERE m.Symbol LIKE 'EURUSD%' AND m.Login IN (SELECT u.Login FROM mt5_users u WHERE u."Group" LIKE 'real%') AND m."Action" = 0
                      ) 
) ComputedValues
```